# Select integers from a given range

Tags: python

I need to select 6 integers from `range(1, 51)` such that no two consecutive integers are selected. `(1, 3, 6, 9, 13, 28)` is a valid selection but `(1, 3, 4, 9, 13, 28)` is not. I need to build a list of all such possible combinations, with each combination in a tuple. Instead of a list a generator will also do. I understand I need to use something like `itertools.combinations` here, but I can't figure out how to eliminate the tuples with consecutive values. I wrote this code,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 51), 6))
>>> len(l)
13983816
```

That is the length I am expecting if there were no constraints on what tuples can be selected, i.e, `50!/(44!6!)`. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `all` with a generator expression:

```
>>> t = (1,3,4,9,13,28)
>>> all( x-y > 1 for x, y in zip(t[1:], t))
False
>>> t = (1,3,6,9,13,28)
>>> all( x-y > 1 for x, y in zip(t[1:], t))
True
```

**Code:**

```
import itertools
for t in itertools.combinations(range(1, 20), 6):
    if all( x-y > 1 for x, y in zip(t[1:], t)):
        #do something with t
```

Comment: Maybe through a gen exp in there. `(numbers for numbers in itertools.combinations(range(1,50),6) if all(x-y > 1 for x,y in zip(t[numbers:], numbers)))`

Comment: I suppose technically OP needed a list, so list comp it instead :). Should come up to about 7 million?

Comment: @adsmith A genexp will do nicely too. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Sabyasachi thank Ashwini! I never would have thought of that `zip` magic.

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import combinations, imap
from operator import add
from functools import partial

result = imap(partial(map, add, range(6)), combinations(range(1, 46), 6))
```

This solution makes use of a bijection from the desired combinations to the set of all combinations of 6 integers from 1 to 45. We pick 6 increasing numbers `x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5` from 1 to 45, then compute

```
x0, x1+1, x2+2, x3+3, x4+4, x5+5
```

This new combination is guaranteed to fall within the range 1-50 and have no consecutive numbers, and any desired combination `y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5` can be produced by the unique choice of x values

```
y0, y1-1, y2-2, y3-3, y4-4, y5-5
```

This works a few times faster than a solution based around filtering out the undesired combinations. The downside is that it takes longer to understand. I had to write a substantial amount of explanation for this, while the other solution is much more straightforward. With longer combinations, this algorithm would have a substantial advantage. For example, if we were picking 16 numbers instead of 6, the other algorithm would consider about 1212 times the number of combinations this algorithm would.

Comment: Would this guarantee that it exhausts ALL combinations?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Yep. All valid combinations will be produced once and exactly once.

Comment: I will accept Ashwini's answer since it's more direct to my question, but thanks for the mathematical perspective. :) +1

Comment: I wrote my answer without the benefit of seeing this - but clearly you and I had the same idea. +1!

Comment: For 1-50 this is 3x faster (assuming you exhaust the generator right away by casting to a list).  Speed doesn't always matter, but 3x is a nice improvement.

Comment: @sberry - 3x faster? I make it about 2x (see my answer...). And that doesn't count the time saved for not doing the comparison.

Comment: @Floris: My guess is the extra overhead comes from the checking of each combination for being valid.  Eliminating the combinations that don't work is only part of the improvement.

Comment: @sberry - I see. I didn't realize you had benchmarked the difference. Then yes, 3x makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, your first (lowest) value cannot be "any one of 50" values - it has to be less than or equal to 40 since `(40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50)` is the "last valid tuple". There must always be 5 "unused values" in between the ones you pick, so the simplest way to achieve this is to select "unconstrained" values from 1 to 45, then add 0, 1, 2, ... 5 to the (sorted) values you get.

Thus:

```
for t in itertools.combinations(range(1,46), 6):
    print tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(t, (0,1,2,3,4,5)))
```

This is more efficient as it doesn't generate any combinations it won't use. With the numbers you are talking about that is significant. Original = `50!/(44!*6!)`, new = `45!/(39!*6!)`. That makes it about 2x more efficient (`50*49*48*47*46*45 / (45*44*43*42*41*40)`) ~ `1.95`... (and thanks user2357112 for pointing out the glaring arithmetic mistake I made - there was an extra factor `6!` that had crept in...)

Comment: You messed up your N choose K computation. It's really only generating about half the combinations the other way does.

Comment: @Sabyasachi - yes I saw that after I posted. I think my explanation of the increased efficiency (1404x) still adds some value...

Comment: could you check it again? I think (50!/44!)/(45!/40!) is 78 though.

Comment: Isn't the first term, 50c6?

Comment: @Floris ah! Correction  in your post it should be new  = 45!/(39!6!)

Comment: Whoops, wrong correction. 40! should be 39!. I see Sabyasachi got it before I did.

Comment: Shouldn't `range(1,45)` be `range(1,46)`, since OP needs 50 as well?

Comment: Thanks both of you for pointing out my mistake. I think I fixed. It's late I should be sleeping...

Comment: @thefourtheye - yes. See earlier comment about sleep... thanks! fixed.